# Array of C strings, initialized with string literals

Tags: c++, arrays

The [Ghostscript interpreter API](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/API.htm) has a function

```
GSDLLEXPORT int GSDLLAPI gsapi_init_with_args(void *instance, int argc, char **argv)
```

The final argument `argv` is a pointer to an array of C strings, which are interpreted as command-line arguments. I obviously cannot change the signature of the function `gsapi_init_with_args` to take a `const char **` argument instead.

If I were willing to ignore (or silence) the `deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'` warning, then I would write simply

```
char *gs_argv[] = {"", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dBATCH", ...};
```

and pass `gs_argv` as the final argument. But I would prefer to fix my code so that I am not relying on an external function to behave in the way I expect it to (and effectively treat `gs_argv` as `const char**`).

Is there any simple way to declare `gs_argv` as an array of pointers to (non-`const`) C strings, and initialize its elements with string literals? (That is, using a similar approach to how I can initialize a single C string: using `char c_str[] = "abc"`.) The best I can think of is to use

```
const char *gs_argv0[] = {"", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dBATCH", ...};
```

and then copy the contents, element by element, into `gs_argv`.

---

Please note that I understand why the compiler gives this warning (and have read the answers to, among others, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896329/warning-converting-from-string-const-to-char-in-initalizing-array-of-c-strings)). I am asking for a solution, rather than an explanation.

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821800/extract-some-command-line-args-before-passing-remainder-to-legacy-code/24822073#24822073

Comment: did you try to const_cast, when calling function, or reinterpret_cast it?

Comment: Submit a patch to GS maintainers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
char arg1[] = "";
char arg2[] = "-dNOPAUSE";
char arg3[] = "-dBATCH";

char* gs_argv0[] = {arg1, arg2, arg3, NULL};
int argc = sizeof(gs_argv0)/sizeof(gs_argv0[0]) - 1;
gsapi_init_with_args(instance, argc, gs_argv0)
```

Comment: I didn't know that *`argv[argc]`* should be NULL. I fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @KubaOber I didn't specify this in the question and it's not explicitly mentioned in the API docs. But it does say 'The arguments are the same as the "C" main function', which I guess implies `argv[argc]` should be a null pointer.

Comment: As much as I like some of the other answers, this seems like the most sensible minimal modification.

Answer (score 1):

Create copies of the string literals using `strdup`. This is more verbose, but fixes the warning.

```
char* gs_argv0[NARGS];
gs_argv0[0] = strdup("");
gs_argv0[1] = strdup("-dNOPAUSE");
// ...
```

Note that you will also need to free the memory allocated by `strdup` if you want to prevent leaks.

You might also want to add a comment to your code saying why you are doing this, to make it clear for future readers.

Comment: You should add a notice, that `strdup()` leaves the caller to care about freeing memory after use.

Comment: `char* gs_argv0[nargs];` is not standard C++ when `nargs` is not a [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

Answer (score 1):

If you can *guarantee* that the function will not modify the non-const parameter, then it is acceptable to use `const_cast` in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Since this code requires C++11, there's a lower cost C++11 solution in another answer below.** I'm leaving this one for posterity.

There are pretty much two choices: ignore it and `const_cast`, or do the right thing. Since this is modern C++, you're supposed to have nice, RAII classes. Thus, the simplest, safest thing to do is to safely wrap such an array.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/args-cstrings-32484688
#include <initializer_list>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

class Args {
   struct str_vector : std::vector<char*> {
      ~str_vector() { for (auto str : *this) free(str); }
   } m_data;
   void append_copy(const char * s) {
      assert(s);
      auto copy = strdup(s);
      if (copy) m_data.push_back(copy); else throw std::bad_alloc();
   }
public:
   Args(std::initializer_list<const char*> l) {
      for (auto str : l) append_copy(str);
      m_data.push_back(nullptr);
   }
   template <std::size_t N>
   Args(const char * const (&l)[N]) {
      for (auto str : l) append_copy(str);
      m_data.push_back(nullptr);
   }
   /// Initializes the arguments with a null-terminated array of strings.
   template<class C, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<C, char const**>::value>::type>
   Args(C l) {
      while (*l) append_copy(*l++);
      m_data.push_back(nullptr);
   }
   /// Initializes the arguments with an array of strings with given number of elements.
   Args(const char ** l, size_t count) {
      while (count--) append_copy(*l++);
      m_data.push_back(nullptr);
   }
   Args(Args && o) = default;
   Args(const Args &) = delete;
   size_t size() const { return m_data.size() - 1; }
   char ** data() { return m_data.data(); }
   bool operator==(const Args & o) const {
      if (size() != o.size()) return false;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i)
         if (strcmp(m_data[i], o.m_data[i]) != 0) return false;
      return true;
   }
};
```

Let's see how it works:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int gsapi_init_with_args(void*, int argc, char** argv) {
   for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
      std::cout << "arg " << i << "=" << argv[i] << std::endl;
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
   Args args1 { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
   const char * args2i[] { "foo", "bar", "baz", nullptr };
   Args args2 { (const char **)args2i };
   const char * args3i[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
   Args args3 { args3i };
   const char * const args4i[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
   Args args4 { args4i };
   const char * args5i[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
   Args args5 { args5i, sizeof(args5i)/sizeof(args5i[0]) };

   assert(args1 == args2);
   assert(args2 == args3);
   assert(args3 == args4);
   assert(args4 == args5);

   gsapi_init_with_args(nullptr, args1.size(), args1.data());
}
```

Output:

```
arg 0=foo
arg 1=bar
arg 2=baz
```

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive solution to the problem. What's the reason for the member class derived from `std::vector<char*>`? I would have used a `std::vector<char*>` member of `Args` and `free`d the memory in `Args::~Args`.

Comment: @StephenPowell The container itself should be a resource handle and must free the resources. `str_vector` is such a container. It's not `Args` job to manage the memory of such a container. That's proper C++ design. Moreover, that's the only way to exception safety. If `Args` constructor would throw, its destructor will never run, but the `m_data`'s will. Generally speaking, if you have to manage a resource manually in C++, outside of a container, you're probably doing something very wrong.

Comment: As written, this requires C++14, no? (`Args(Args && o) = default;`, etc.) But it's easy enough to implement the same idea without any fancy modern stuff.

Answer (score 1):

A C++14 solution.

```
#define W(x) \
  (([](auto& s)->char* \
   { \
     static char r[sizeof(s)]; \
     strcpy (r, s); \
     return r; \
   })(x))

char* argv[] = 
  { W("--foo=bar", 
    W("baz"),
    nullptr
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to const_cast it:

```
gsapi_init_with_args(instance, argc, const_cast<char**>(argv));
```

Maybe it will help with fixing warning.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by n.m.'s C++14 version, here's a C++11 version. The trick is to use an evaluated empty lambda expression to generate a fresh type, so that each instantiation of `W__` is unique.

```
template <typename T, int N> static char * W__(const char (&src)[N], T) {
   static char storage[N];
   strcpy(storage, src);
   return storage;
}

#define W(x) W__(x, []{})

char * argv[] = {
   W("foo"),
   W("bar")
};
```

The `static` in front of `W__`'s return type means that `W__` has internal linkage and won't bloat the object file with extra symbols. It has nothing to do with the `static` in front  of `storage`, as the latter indicates the static storage duration for the local variable. The code below would be perfectly valid, but of course doing the wrong thing and having undefined behavior:

```
template <typename T, int N> static char * BAD(const char (&src)[N], T) {
   char storage[N];
   strcpy(storage, src);
   return storage;
}
```

Since a lambda has to be evaluated, you can't simply make its type a template argument:

```
template<typename> void G();
G<decltype([]{})>(); // doesn't work
```